# What is the meaning of symbol "|"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am reading a paper and there is a picture here:

[image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AfCE5_LQDOZ9Pdl_W-PWOQ2wP-Vf772s]

just beneath the "while" word, you would see "|" symbol. What is it? I have searched 
http://web.uvic.ca/~salam/math_symbols.html 
and
https://www.wikizero.com/en/List_of_logic_symbols

I cannot find it.

Comment: It is 'such that'. Its used in set notation.

Comment: That just means "such that".  For instance, $S=\{s\in \mathbb Z \,|\, s\equiv 0 \pmod 3\}$ denotes the set of all integers which are divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: whatever is after that symbol is the property that all elements of the set must follow. There can be multiple properties.

Comment: ... so $C_k$ is constructed by looping over all sets contained in $L_{k-1}$ and adding every possible single object not already contained in that subset to these; but we remove all those sets again that have a $k-1$-element subset not in $L_{k-1}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several common ways to denote a set of particular elements.  The | is a vertical pipe, which can be typed as "\mid" in LaTeX. Another equivalent option is to use a colon.

So, if we wanted to talk about the even natural numbers, any of these would work. 
$$
\begin{split}
\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \text{ is even} \}\\
\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n \text{ is even}\}\\
\{ 2n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}\\
\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid (\exists m) [n = 2m]\}
\end{split}
$$
This is called [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). It is not formally defined, but is a part of informal mathematical language that has developed along with the need to specify sets inside mathematical texts.

The other use of $|$ in logic is to represent the [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke), but that is not at all what is suggested in the question above. In programming, $|$ is sometimes used for OR or for bitwise OR.  Wikipedia has a longer list of uses in mathematics in their article on "[vertical bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)".

Comment: Actually, I would use $\{2n\colon n \in\mathbb N\}$ (different spacing).